# How to avoid/ignore OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException when element is not found?

Tags: .net, selenium, exception, webdriverwait

I want to be sure that that a given element is not in the DOM or if it is present in the DOM it is no longer displayed.

In order to do so I configure `WebDriverWait` to ignore `NoSuchElementException` and:

```
public static void WaitForElementToDisappear(IWebDriver driver)
{
     var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
     wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException));
     wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.ClassName("ClassName")).Displayed == false);
}
```

unfortunately the exceotion is not ignored and the test fails the moment it is thrown.

How to deal with that?

EDIT: I found out that unfortunately this is a desired bahaviour of wait, it doesn't throw the exception until the timeout, so my way is absolutely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use already existing `ExpectedConditions`?

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.ClassName("ClassName")));
```

None existing element is considered invisible, you can see it in the [source code](https://github.com/DotNetSeleniumTools/DotNetSeleniumExtras/blob/master/src/WaitHelpers/ExpectedConditions.cs), notice the comments in the `catch (NoSuchElementException)` block

```
public static Func<IWebDriver, bool> InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By locator)
{
    return (driver) =>
    {
        try
        {
            var element = driver.FindElement(locator);
            return !element.Displayed;
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            // Returns true because the element is not present in DOM. The
            // try block checks if the element is present but is invisible.
            return true;
        }
        catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
        {
            // Returns true because stale element reference implies that element
            // is no longer visible.
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

It's also mentioned in the [docs](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_InvisibilityOfElementLocated.htm)

> An expectation for checking that an element is either invisible or not
>   present on the DOM.

Comment: Because it checks for invisibility, not presence in DOM.

Comment: @Yoda it checks for presence as well. I'll update the answer.

Comment: It have just thrown:
`OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".className"}`

Comment: @Yoda `InvisibilityOfElementLocated` catches `NoSuchElementException`, it won't throw it.

Comment: Ok, it didn't fail the test debugger just picked it up, I need to turn on `Just My Code` option. Thanks!